# Is it okay to use law of attraction to get prayers answered from the Almighty or is it shirk?

Tags: dua

Is it okay to use law of attraction to get prayers answered from the Almighty or is it shirk? Because I have prayed and prayed and I didn't get any response? I was thinking maybe I was doing something wrong? Or should I just leave my prayers and be happy regardless?

Comment: It depends what you mean with "use of law of attraction". To think that the universe will somehow return whatever you wish just because you think about it (and somehow trick yourself that it will come true), that is an issue from an islamic point of view. But if you define it in a psychologically point of view, without the "universe will give you what you wish" talk, then you might come out clean from an islamic point of view, and this is while you understand that whatever you achieved is from God. **In order to get a better answer, please explain what you mean with "use law of attraction"**

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe your question goes beyond "the law of attraction" whatever that means. Allah does not confine Himself to your/our wishes or wants; and yet, I have found all my prayers were answered (or at least that's what I noticed), albeit not necessarily at the time, place, or in the manner I had pictured it would be.

Bear in mind that Allah is Almighty. Beyond, way beyond, the scope of your imagination. And have a little more respect for that. At the same time, it is good that you believe He will answer your prayers because He will if you didn't ask for something harmful or wrong (maybe even unwittingly), and if He sees that as within the bounds of reason and religion. But not necessarily the way or time you expect. Your time frame is not the same as His. Also if your request is not good for you, it is always His discretion to grant it or not, and if not it will always be just.

How many times does the Quran ask us to be patient or promise great rewards for the patient? Be patient. There is always a wisdom and benefit regardless if He responded the way you wanted or expected...or not. And be always grateful for what Allah has given you and try to see His concern even if it is not obvious. Human beings are fully capable of this, of grasping subtleties, of patience, of gratitude. Feel free to ask for more and different requests. Perhaps you will notice another gift and response, giving you more patience for the first.

From Surat Al-e-Imran 3:200:

> 200. O you who believe, be patient and call for patience, and stand firm, and reverence Allah that you may succeed.

The Arabic word "tuflihoon" (translated here "succeed") is the same root as the word "fallah" used in the *athan* — meaning "Come to salat! Come to **Success**!" So the "success" here is not only of this world (such as being granted a du'a) but of the next, Hereafter.

And you are not alone in having to endure some passage of time before Allah's response arrives. The prophets also had to endure pain and be patient.

Surat Al-An'aam 6:34:

> Rejected were the messengers before you: with patience and constancy
>   they bore their rejection and their suffering (pain), until Our
>   aid/victory did reach them: there is none that can alter the words
>   (and decrees) of Allah. Already you have received some account of
>   those messengers.

So if you are seeking a magic bullet or a way to expedite Allah's response time, the best advice is in the Quran: be patient. The best things come to those who wait. Instead of the "law of attraction," try the "law of stick-to-it-iveness" otherwise known as "don't give up so easily." Think larger than that. Look at the night sky. The Creator of this magnificence promised to reward the patient. Meanwhile, don't ignore all the good things He does and has done for us/you and free your mind from the idea of scheduling God. Let it happen in His time, His way, and Allah knows best, the Omniscient, the All-Merciful.